# What is the minimal $N$ so that ${\hbox Aut}(S_n)$ can be embedded into $S_N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

So the automorphisms of $S_3$ are isomorphic to $S_3$. But for $n > 3$, is there a known bound on $N(n)$ so that automorphisms of $S_n$ can be embedded as a subgroup of $S_N$? The trivial bound is $N = n!$ but this seems ridiculously pessimistic. Can someone come up with a better bound, or the exact minimal value for $N$?

Comment: When $n$ is different from $6$ (and $0,1,2$), $\mathrm{Aut}(S_n)=\mathrm{Inn}(S_n)\simeq S_n$, so the minimal $N$ is $n$.